# Proof of natural log

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $L:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, that $L(1)=0$, and that $L'(x)=1/x$ for all $x>0$.

Then $L(2^n)>n/2$ for all $n\in N$.

This implies that $\sup(L)=\infty$, and a similar argument shows that $\inf L = -\infty$. By the inverse-function teorem, it follows that $L$ is a bijection from $(0,\infty)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ and that its inverse $E=L^{-1}$ is differentiable. Show that $E'(t)=E(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Obviously the function is the natural log, but for this I can not use the properties of $\ln$ nor integration. So how do I show this without knowing what the function is or its inverse?

Comment: Which part do you want help with?

Comment: I'm not sure how to express $L$, so I can't then find $L^-1$ and so I can't find $E'(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to find $E'(t)$ for this problem.
Sometimes you can show two functions are equal without ever actually knowing
what either function is.

Since $E$ is the inverse of $L$, for all $x \in (0, \infty)$ you have
$E(L(x)) = x$.

Presuming you are allowed to use differentiation and the Chain Rule,
you can take the derivatives of both sides with respect to $x$.
You should then be able to relate $E'(L(x))$ to $E(L(x))$.

**Edit:** It occurred to me later that the solution might come even
easier if we write $L(E(t)) = t$.

Comment: So then $(E(L(t)))'=E'(L(t))L'(t)=E'(L(t))/t=E'(L(t))/E(L(t))$. Do I know that $E'(L(t))/E(L(t))$ is equal to 1 somehow?

Comment: That's the derivative of $E(L(x))$. What is the derivative of $x$?

Comment: $x'=1$ So really $(E(L(t)))'=(t)'=1$, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You know that $L$ is the logarithm, so that $L(2^n) = n L(2) > n/2$.  Here is how it works: since
$$ L(2^n) = \int_1^{2^n} L'(t) \, dt = \int_1^{2^n} \frac 1t \, dt$$ you can use the substitution
$$s^n = t,\quad ns^{n-1} ds = dt, \quad \frac{dt}{t} =  n\frac{ds}{s}$$ to get
$$ \int_1^{2^n} \frac 1t \, dt = n \int_1^2 \frac 1s \, ds \ge n \int_1^2 \frac 12 \, ds= \frac n2.$$